# Can't deploy old Firebase app to new site

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to deploy a Firebase Vue.js app to a new Firebase hosting site.
In src/firebase.js and dist/src/firebase.jx I've changed the API key, authDomain, etc. to the new site, but when I run `firebase deploy` it finishes successfully but shows the old project console address and the old hosting URL in the terminal, and does not deploy to the new site.

What have I missed that is still pointing to the old site?

Comment: The `firebase` CLI uses the configuration in the `.firebaserc` file

Comment: thanks.  tried renaming that file , get same result.

Comment: Why would you rename it? You should be editing the project details in it